# Draw circuit diagrams with custom shapes?

Tags: schematics, software, drawing

I want all the benefits of dedicated schematic drawing software but I often don't like the way the diagrams actually look. I know it sounds trivial, but I find it easier to read nicely hand drawn diagrams than all-red wireframe type ones.

Is there a decent piece of software where for example I can customise the shape or colour of opamps/wires/transistors etc?

Comment: I often print the schematics in black and white, highlight and redline them by hand (with color, if necessary).  Finally, I sometimes scan them for archiving.  Low tech solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible in Altium Designer. You can design your own custom parts and build your circuit with them. All of the circuit elements (even the IC and capcitors) in the following picture are designed by me.

You can learn about creating custom component libraries in Altium Designer from [here](http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Creating+Library+Components+Tutorial).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

LTspice has the option of changing colors and fonts to an extent.

[LTspice IV](http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/#LTspice)

[image: Color scheme]